# Error in the "Expression" window on STM32CubeIDE

Tags: function, variables, stm32

I want to display the value of these two variables and also their position in memory.

I can see the green one on the right in the Expressions window ... the red one cannot.

```
char my_data_RAM[] = "I'm in RAM";
char const my_data_FLASH[] = "I'm in FLASH";

int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
    char f = my_data_FLASH[1];
    char r = my_data_RAM[0]; //var. locale

while(1) {
}

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qjr1.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zLtl.jpg)

Any solutions?

I think the problem is due to 'char const' initialisation ?

Comment: Do you actually use either of these arrays for anything? The CubeIDE build process removes any functions and data that are not used anywhere.

Comment: I have replaced the photo in my original post with a more updated one. If you open it, you will notice that the variable 'my_data_RAM' has no problem being displayed in the Expressions section, while 'my_data_FLASH' gives a red error. Thus:                                                                
        char f = my_data_FLASH[0];
 char r = my_data_RAM[0];

Comment: @KaleM The compiler will still optimise away such a simple expression, since `f` is itself unused. Try something like `strncpy(my_data_RAM, my_data_FLASH, sizeof my_data_RAM);` Then your FLASH symbol will be included.

Comment: Alternatively, open your project settings, go to `C/C++ build -> Settings -> MCU GCC Linker -> General` and unselect `Discard unused sections`.